# How to simplify the a rxjs operator based function

Tags: typescript, rxjs6

How can we simplify the below mentioned function, basically i want to get rid of nested map operations.

```
  static getEmployees(data: Observable<any>): Observable<Employee[]> {
   return data.pipe(map(data=>{
        return data.map(item=>{
          return  {
            id: item.id,
            first_name: item.first_name,
            last_name: item.last_name,
            age:item.age,
            is_active:item.is_active
          }
        })
    })) as Observable<Employee[]>;
  }
```

Comment: It's not a nested map, exactly - one's an RxJS observable map, the other is a vanilla JS array map.

Answer (score 0):

**from()** transforms the incoming array to a stream of single elements that are processed by the **map()** operator and transformed back into an array by **toArray()** when the stream completes.

In terms of readability, you could argue if it really is a simplification. I hope it helps.

```
    static getEmployees(data: Observable<any>): Observable<Employee[]> {
        return data.pipe(
            switchMap(x => from(x)),
            map(item => ({
                id: item.id,
                first_name: item.first_name,
                last_name: item.last_name,
                age: item.age,
                is_active: item.is_active
            })),
            toArray()
        ) as Observable<Employee[]>;
     }
```